# Low performance when extracting frames from video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I am writing a video processing application and have hit a bit of a snag.

The idea is to extract frames (images) from a video file, process them on the GPU and then write them back to a new video file.

So far i have been successful in doing this using [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).

The only problem is that extracting the frames takes a **very long time** (in the 200ms region). This is way to much, as added to the GPU processing time and the time it takes to write to a new file, it results in a total process duration of about 700ms per frame.

This is how i grab the frames:

```
 FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoLocation);
 frameGrabber.start();

 frameGrabber.setFrameNumber(frameNumber);
 frame = frameGrabber.grabImage();
```

Pretty standard, nothing special, and it works. I am able to process the frame, convert it to a bitmap, etc...

As i have said before, the bottom two instructions (setting the frame number and grabbing the image) take a very very long time. Writing the frames also takes a fair bit.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has any input regarding this issue. Maybe i'm not setting up something correctly, maybe there is another solution that is faster.

Comment: What processing time do you expect?

Comment: Ever the optimist, i'm hoping to 1:1 or 1:2 for the entire process (15 sec video would take 30 sec to process). I'm asking if it can be done faster. If it can't, that's life...

Comment: Do you initialize and start frame grabber every time when you want to grab image ?

Comment: No,  I initialize and start it only once per video file. I have profiled the app,  and setting the frame time and grabbing takes the most time.

Comment: I am having the same issue, now am looking for alternative solutions, I tried using the [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) but setDataSource() fails on some devices. Will let u know if I find any other solution.

Comment: I tried it. using flv file is faster than mp4....